# Gmap4rails Gmap is not Defined Error in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

i want to integrate gmap4rails Api in my Active_admin ,Getting error gmap is not define here the code is :-
map.js

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers([
    {
      "lat": 0,
      "lng": 0,
      "picture": {
        "url": "http://people.mozilla.com/~faaborg/files/shiretoko/firefoxIcon/firefox-32.png",
        "width":  32,
        "height": 32
      },
      "infowindow": "hello!"
    }
  ]);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
  });
```

including all Source from Gmaprrails in application layout

```
Application.html.erb


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
                            <script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.23&key= AIzaSyDfo9bkA0O99tPFLgzv41p-nEiIa6qHOfY "></script>
              <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus/master/dist/markerclusterer.min.js"></script>
              <script src='//cdn.rawgit.com/printercu/google-maps-utility-library-v3-read-only/master/infobox/src/infobox_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
               <!-- only if you need custom infoboxes -->

              <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
                        <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
                          <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'gmaps4rails' %>
                            <%= gmaps({
                                    "map_options" => { "zoom" => 2, "auto_adjust" => false},
                                        "markers"     => { "data" => markers } })%>
              <%= yield :javascripts %>    

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

including assets in application.js
    Application.js

```
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require underscore
//= require_tree .

_map.html.erb

<div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>

admin /branch.rb

    @branch = Branch.all
         @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@branch) do |branch, marker|
            marker.lat branch.lat
        marker.lng branch.lng
         end
        render partial: 'active_admin/branches/map', locale:{hash: @hash}
    end
please help me out !!!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should put your application js file to Active_admin.js